# access softlink name which invokes a bash script

Tags: c, linux, bash, arguments

The c code below prints the soft-link name using which it was invoked:

```c
/* file: checkc.c */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
}
```

> $ gcc -o checkc checkc.c 
> $ ln -s checkc ppc 
> $ ./ppc 
> ./ppc

However, the same idea does not work with bash scripts:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# file: checkbash.bash

echo $(basename $(readlink -f $0))
```

> $ ln -s checkbash.bash ppb 
> $ ./ppb 
> checkbash.bash

i.e. it continues to print the original script name as arg0 even if it is invoked via a soft-link of different name:

Is it possible to access the soft-link name using which the bash script was used invoked?

Comment: It's just `$0`. Why are you going through the trouble of using `readlink` in Bash, when you don't do so in C?

Comment: @Cheatah your comment does not contribute in any way for the question asked